# Add typings to firebase collection query

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function like:

```
async queryAll(): Promise<Product[]> {
  const response = await this.firestore.collection('products').get();
  return response.docs.map(a => a.data());
}
```

And getting error:

> Type 'DocumentData[]' is not assignable to type 'Product[]'.   Type
>   'DocumentData' is missing the following properties from type
>   'Product': id, name

How can I add proper return typings for this method?

What can I see in `firebase/index.ts.d`, `get` function types looks like (I am using npm firebase package):

`get(options?: GetOptions): Promise<QuerySnapshot<T>>;`

But not sure how to apply this to my code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found solution, need to use
[withConverter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.FirestoreDataConverter) in order to add typings when retrieving data from firestore collections

Added working example, `result` from `dbQuery` function should have proper type i.g. `Product[]`

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { firebaseConfig } from '../firebaseConfig';

export interface Product {
  name: string;
}
 
export const productConverter = {
  toFirestore(product: Product): firebase.firestore.DocumentData {
    return { name: product.name };
  },

  fromFirestore(
    snapshot: firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot,
    options: firebase.firestore.SnapshotOptions
  ): Product {
    const data = snapshot.data(options)!;
    return { name: data.name }
  }
};

async function dbQuery() {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const db = firebase.firestore();
  const response = await db.collection("products").withConverter(productConverter).get();
  const result = response.docs.map(doc => {
    const data = doc.data();
    return data;
  });

  return result; // result type is Product[]
}
```

Comment: bsekula can you please post full code with your `withConverter`? Having same issue.

Comment: Updated answer with example

Comment: link is a 404. .

Comment: Fixed broken link

Answer (score 4):

I find its very simple to use TypeScript's [Type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) feature for this.

```js
await db.collection('products').get() as firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot<Product>;
```

For single documents:

```js
await db.collection('products').doc('12345').get() as firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot<Product>;
```

For snapshots:

```js
db.collection('products')
  .onSnapshot((snapshot: firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot<Product>) => {
    for (const doc of snapshot.docs) {
      const product = doc.data();
    }
  });
```

When you call `data()` on the document snapshot, its type will be of `Product`.

Comment: How would you use that in a onSnapShot() listener?

Comment: @MorenoMdz I added an example for collection snapshots

Comment: Hey, I ended up using the suggested types from the SDK: 
`querySnapshot: firebase.firestore.DocumentData`

Answer (score 1):

Generic solution using [withConverter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FirestoreDataConverter) to assign a generic type to a collection

```
export function assignTypes<T extends object>() {
  return {
    toFirestore(doc: T): firestore.DocumentData {
      return doc
    },
    fromFirestore(snapshot: firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot): T {
      return snapshot.data()! as T
    },
  }
}
```

Then, use it like this:

```
type User = { id: string, name: string }

const users = firestore
  .collection('users')
  .withConverter(assignTypes<User>())
  .get() // Now of type firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot<User>
```